# Java Unicode Characters

Tags: java, unicode

I'm familiar with problems with ascii. The problem is I have no experience with same problems in unicode characters. For example, how to return the word that occurs most frequently given a string array containing words? Thanks in advance!

p.s.: You can always use an array which length is "256" to represent all the characters in ASCII while you can't do that when it comes to unicode. Is HashMap a must and the best way to solve the problem? I heard that there are better ways to solve it. Below is what I can think of:

```
    String str = "aa df ds df df"; // assume they are Unicode
    String[] words = str.split(" ");
    HashMap<String, Integer> map  = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    for (String word : words){
        if (map.containsKey(word)){
            int f = map.get(word);
            map.put(word, f+1);
        } else{
            map.put(word, 1);
        }
    }

    int max = 0;
    String maxWord = ""; 

    for (String word : words){
        int f = map.get(word);
        if (f > max){
            max = f;
            maxWord = word;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(maxWord + " " +max);
```

Comment: What about that problem would be any different with ASCII or Unicode?

Comment: @TedHopp You can always use an array which length is "256" to represent all the characters in ASCII while you can't do that when it comes to unicode. Is HashMap a must and the best way to solve the problem? I heard that there are better ways to solve it.

Comment: It would be exactly the same.  It doesn't even need to be words, it can be an array of anything and you could return the most frequently used object in the array exactly the same way by implementing comparable in your object (which String already has implemented, so you don't even need to do that) and then using CompareTo().

Comment: I don't see how you would use an array of length 256 to solve the "most frequent word" problem. I agree that there are problems where the small size of the ASCII encoding makes things simpler, but that problem isn't one of them. Every problem is different; without something specific, it's hard to provide advice.

Comment: @GameKyuubi Could you solve the problem using your method? I added my code on the post, hashmap is all I can think of :(

Comment: @TedHopp Could you solve the problem using your method? I only know how to solve it using hash map

Comment: I'd solve it more or less as you did. (Perhaps a minor optimization or two is possible.) However, my point all along is that I don't see how you would solve it any differently if you restricted the character set to ASCII. (Unless you also assumed words were always at most two letters and used an array of length 256*256 = 65536...)

Comment: @TedHopp Yea.. Seems to be the same.. I didn't think it thoroughly before..lol

Comment: @TedHopp There's indeed a way without using hash map. I just figured it out. Please see the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Inspired by GameKyuubi. It can be solved using array sort and count the most frequently used word using constatnt space. 
    Arrays.sort(words);
    int max = 0;
    int count = 0;
    String maxWord = "";
    String prev = "";
    for (String word : words){
        if (prev.equals("") || word.equals(prev)){
            count++;
        } else{
            count = 1;
        }

        if (max < count){
            max = count;
            maxWord = word;
        }
        prev = word;

    }
    System.out.println(maxWord + " " +max);
```

Comment: This avoids a `Hashmap` but at the cost of creating an O(n log n) algorithm (because of the sort) instead of one that is O(n).